# ArcGIS 10.2.2 make a specific query with IF

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, esri-geodatabase

I'm using ArcGIS 10.2.2 with a geodatabase stored in a file, I'm not using ArcGIS server. I want to do a specific query in it. I want to do a query which look like  :

```
SELECT *, IF(column1==column2,'1','0') FROM mytable
```

Is it possible ? Where can I enter a query like that ?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include where you are storing this geodatabase (e.g. file, personal, Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, etc), please?

Comment: If you are using a file geodatabase,  please state that,  not "geodatabase in a file"

Answer (score 1):

File geodatabases,  unlike enterpise geodatabases, are not built on top of a RDBMS.  Nor are they implemenred inside Access like personal geodatabases. This gives them a performance advantage,  but comes at the cost of a rudimentary SQL implementation. If `IF` doesn't work inside the column list, you'll need to find a different way to manifest this recoding.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select features from a specific table, use the [Select By Attributes](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000071000000) tool.

Your where clause would be:

```
column1 = column2
```